# Sending json collections to Perforce depot

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, perforce, p4python

I am trying to send json collections from a Flask server to remote Perforce depot using P4Python.

Is there a way to do that through Python?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately your question is not on topic for this site as it is too broad. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and consider updating your question in line with the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy for doing this via P4Python is going to be about the same as doing it via the command line or one of the other scripting APIs: you'll need to create a workspace, write the file to the workspace, and use `p4 add` and `p4 submit`.

There isn't an API that lets you pipe data directly into the server to be converted into a depot file.